# Char array in linked list causes core dump

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list, strcpy

I created a linked list program it works perfect with ints in c.
but if change the parameter to char array, and try to do a strcpy it causes a core dump.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    char mac[25];
    struct node * next;
};
typedef struct node *list;

int main(void) {

   lista c;

   c = creoLista();
   c = insert_start(c, "aa:bb:cc:dd:e1");
   c = insert_start(c, "aa:bb:cc:dd:e2");
   c = insert_start(c, "aa:bb:cc:dd:e3");

   showList(c);
   return 0;
}

list createList() {
   return NULL;
}

list insert_start(list l1, char val[]) {
    list n;
    n =(list )malloc(sizeof(list));
    strcpy(n->mac,val);
    printf("ADDED: %s en ADDRESS:%p NEXT ADDRESS: %p\n", n->mac,(void *)(&n), (void *) (&n->next));
    n -> next = l1;

    return n;
}

void showList(list l1) {
     while (l1 != NULL){
         printf("Value: %s Address: %p\n",l1 -> mac,(void *) (&l1 -> next) );
         l1 = l1 -> next;
    }
}
```

Any hint on what im doing wrong and why it works with ints and not a char array

thanks

Comment: You have no check for a possible null pointer anywhere in your code.

Comment: [Please don't cast the result of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Comment: This `malloc(sizeof(list))` allocates space to hold a pointer. May be you need this `malloc(sizeof(struct node))` to allocate space to hold a node rather than a pointer to a node?

Comment: Wheres `creoLista()` defined? Also, you don't need to cast the printf either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your allocation is wrong, because you made it confusing by `typedef`ing a pointer, don't do that

   ```
   n = malloc(sizeof(*n));
   ```

   is less error prone.
2. Check the return value of `malloc()` and there is no need for the cast, so

   ```
   n = malloc(sizeof(*n));
   if (n == NULL)
       return NULL;
   ```
3. You are printing the `n->next` pointer's address before initializing it, change this

   ```
   printf("ADDED: %s en ADDRESS:%p NEXT ADDRESS: %p\n", n->mac,(void *)     (&n), (void *) (&n->next));
   n->next = l1;
   ```

   to

   ```
   n->next = l1;
   printf("ADDED: %s en ADDRESS:%p NEXT ADDRESS: %p\n", n->mac, (void *)n, (void *)n->next);
   ```
4. You have no function prototypes, so your compiler is using implicit function declaration, which is bad, because it will assume that all the functions return `int`, so you need to add these before the definition of `main()`

   ```
   list createList();
   list insert_start(list l1, char val[]);
   void showList(list l1);
   ```

   specially the first 2 are very important, enable compiler warnings to prevent this.

This is your code fixed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    char mac[25];
    struct node * next;
};
typedef struct node *list;

list insert_start(list l1, char val[]);
void showList(list l1);

int main(void) {
    lista c;

    c = insert_start(NULL, "aa:bb:cc:dd:e1");
    c = insert_start(c, "aa:bb:cc:dd:e2");
    c = insert_start(c, "aa:bb:cc:dd:e3");

    showList(c);
    return 0;
}

list insert_start(list l1, char val[]) {
    list n;

    n = malloc(sizeof(*n));
    if (n == NULL)
        return NULL;
    strcpy(n->mac, val);
    n->next = l1;

    printf("ADDED: %s en ADDRESS:%p NEXT ADDRESS: %p\n", n->mac, (void *)n, (void *)n->next);
    return n;
}

void showList(list l1) {
     while (l1 != NULL) {
        printf("Value: %s Address: %p\n", l1->mac, (void *)l1->next);
        l1 = l1->next;
    }
}
```

and you need a `freeList()` function too.

Comment: I tried changing the code. and it still return a core dump after the second insert_start call

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this allocation:

```
malloc(sizeof(list))
```

It shows the problem with making type-aliases of *pointers* as you here only allocate the size of a pointer and not the whole structure.

Answer (score 0):

`typedef struct node *list;`

`n =(list )malloc(sizeof(list));`

`list` is pointer to struct `node`, malloc() should be passed the size of valid bytes to perform `strcpy` and list could be just `8` bytes if you are working on 64 but machine. Change malloc() allocation to size of pointer points to.